# Создать массив и заполнить его ключ=>значение

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день подскажите как корректно сформировать массив?
Есть массив:

```
[arr_questions] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id_question] => 1
                [question] => Сколько будет 2+2?
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id_question] => 4
                [question] => Сколько будет 5+5?
                [7] => 7
                [8] => 10
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id_question] => 3
                [question] => Сколько будет 4+4?
                [5] => 8
                [6] => 5
            )

    )
```

Перебираю массив и вывожу.
Когда выбираю ответ получаю его ключ `radio`.
И у меня есть `id_question.`
Как добавить в массив ключ`id_question` -> `значение(ключ выбранного ответа)`

Чтобы получился такой массив?

```
[answers] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                    [4] => 7
                    [3] => 6
                )
```

Пока делаю так:
Создаю 2 массива (ответы и ключи вопросов)
Заполняю и потом объединяю через `array_combine`

А можно сразу формировать массив?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно, то у вас есть какая-та форма, в которой есть поля с типом `radio`,  и вам нужно получить из неё `$_POST` или `$_GET` в нужной Вам форме.

Чтобы сразу получить из неё нужный массив можете использовать массивы в `name` атрибуте полей.

Сколько будет `2 + 2` ?

```
<input name="answers[1]" type="radio" value="4">
<input name="answers[1]" type="radio" value="5">
```

Сколько будет `5 + 5`?

```
<input name="answers[4]" type="radio" value="7">
<input name="answers[4]" type="radio" value="10">
```

Получить:

```
$_POST['answers']
```

Comment: Да верно я получаю $_POST['answer'] в котором содержится ключ ответа и также в меня доступен id_question Мне теперь надо каждый раз добавлять в массив ключ значение чтобы получилось

[answers] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                    [4] => 7
                    [3] => 6
                )